# Loop for this particular summation

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Given a pattern... (1 / 2)^2 + (2 / 3)^2 + (3 / 4)^2 + ...

Input is n; which becomes the highest denominator used in the summation of these fractions.

When a user enters n = **2**; the sum is simply (1 / **2**)^2.

When a user enters n = **3**; the sum is (1 / 2)^2 + (2 / **3**)^2

I believe I've solved this problem (we assume the user enters an integer greater than or equal to 2)...

```
int n;
double sum = 0, counter = 2;

n = console.nextInt();

while(counter <= n) {
sum = sum + Math.pow(--counter/++counter, 2);
counter++;
}

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

Is there any "obvious" way to simplify my solution to this problem (whilst remaining as a while-loop)? This is one of the first loops I've ever written. I'm not sure if less variables can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: `--counter/++counter` don't do any effect. division follows after increments

Comment: `--counter/++counter` is counter intuitive. Why not simply write `counter/(counter+1)`?

Comment: For n = 2; counter/(counter+1) makes for (2 / 3)^2. For n = 2; the first sum should be (1 / 2)^2; not (2 / 3)^2.

Comment: @DoctorQuestions did you checked my post ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int n;
double sum = 0, counter=1;

n = console.nextInt();

   while((counter+1) <= n) {
    sum = sum + Math.pow(counter/(counter+1), 2);
    counter++;
    }

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: if t2 is always t1+1 why is it necessary?

Comment: I like it. You can enter the loop without changing the value of counter until the end of the iteration.

Comment: consider accepting the answer, if your problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Why dont simplify it and write this:

```
int n;
double sum = 0, counter = 2;

n = console.nextInt();

while(counter <= n) {
sum = sum + Math.pow((counter - 1)/counter, 2);
counter++;
}

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

i dont know who is computed first (++counter) or (--counter), if (--counter) your response is correct, but dont pollute your code with ++ or --, use them only if you need it.

Comment: "i dont know who is computed first (++counter) or (--counter)," Java always evaluates left-to-right, so the `--counter` is evaluated before the `++counter`.